# more than 3 hard disk in RAID 1 setting up

Tags: windows-7, raid-1

I would like to add 3 mirror Hard disk(RAID 1) by using software base RAID 1. In window 7, I can add only two mirror Hard disk. I would like to be that one data disk and two back up disk.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The inbuilt "Mirrored Disk" option in Windows 7 allows only the creation of a 2-disk mirror.

Perhaps create a mirror between the two disks, and then configure a disk/image backup to the third one?